# Why non-static variables/methods are not accessible inside a static method?

Tags: static, jvm, non-static

Need the reason from JVM side. Explanation of the flow of the JVM is much appreciated(In simply words).

Answer (score 0):

Static variables and methods do not belong to an object, but they exist on an outermost level.

Conversely, non-static variables and methods belong to an instantiated object.

This means that non-static variables and methods are not accessible to static methods because static methods would not have an object on which to operate.

Let me do an example:

Imagine the class Foo is defined as

```java
public class Foo{
  public static int a;
}
```

We can do operations like

```java
public static int main(String[] args){
  Foo.a = 10;
  int b = Foo.a - 5;
}
```

without instantiating an object

```java
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Now think about the following class

```java
public class Bar{
  int a = 10;

  public static void doSomething(){
    this.a = 5;
  }
}
```

We know the keyword `this` refers to the object in use, but `doSomething()` it is not linked to an object, so what object does `this` refer to?

This is why we can't access non-static variables and methods inside a static method.

Answer (score 0):

So to understand this you first need no understand what a static method is. Basically, a static method is a method inside a class that can be called even when the class hasn't been initiated.

These static methods (or variables) exist independently of any initiation of the class.

In general anything static should be avoided as they are kinda an antipattern when it comes to javas object-oriented approach to things.

Comment: First you need to understand the difference between a class and an object to properly explain what a static method is. I am not really saying you don't but your answer comes across like there's a bit of confusion there.